# Repetition of hyphen in shared prefixes

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions, hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a hyphen be used without anything on the right side?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39860/can-a-hyphen-be-used-without-anything-on-the-right-side)

I'm trying to discuss types of semiconductor, there is P-type and N-type. Assuming my hyphenation is correct, should it be '*p- and n-type*' or just '*p and n-type*'?

Comment: I'm quite certain this type of question has been asked recently. The problem is *finding* the original - if it gets asked again next month, who would think to find this one by searching for the particular words in the title? Next time it might be *"Five- and six-sided polygons, or five and six-sided?"*

Comment: I did a search for hyphenation and conjugation before I posted this, nothing relevant came up. If you think you have a better title that still describes my problem, @FumbleFingers, feel free to edit it into one.

Comment: I can only hazard guesses the same as you. Neither of our guesses found the other one, but I *know* it's there. I'll have another think - maybe appending something like *repetition of hyphen in shared prefixes*?

Comment: Top man! My edit to the title was blocked because you were also making the *exact same change!*

Comment: *Hi- and low-five*

Comment: Punctuation questions are neverending, repetitive, and rarely productive of useful answers. The more I think about it, the more I think that punctuation questions of any sort should go first to separate English punctuation exchange. Then we can deal with the questions on English grammar and usage here.

Comment: @John: I think a dedicated *punctuation.se* site might be a specialisation too far, but you've certainly prompted me to notice that neither this nor the earlier question had the [punctuation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) tag, so I've just editted it in to both. If we were all a bit more rigorous about that, you could just set your preferences to ignore that tag, and all would be hunky-dory.

Comment: Given the status of the tags, I'm not surprised. I generally ignore them, after an initial taste, and I suspect others do, too.

Answer (score 4):

It would be *P- and N-type*; writing *P and N-type* leaves it open to the interpretation that you are talking about a single type called "P and N" rather than two types, named "P" and "N".

Answer (score 2):

I would write "P-type and N-type". Describing the technology accurately and unambiguously is more important than annoying grade school English teachers and dictionary pedants.

People may also search your text for "P-type"