# Correct hyphenation for conjunction of hyphenated compound adjectives

Tags: hyphenation

Consider the following sentence:

> The labour-intensive and time-intensive part starts tomorrow.

I want to write this without rewriting the word "intensive."

Is this the correct way to do it?

> The labour- and time-intensive part starts tomorrow.

Note the hyphen hanging after the word labour. Or should there be no hyphen after labour? Can anyone point me to a reference that talks about this?

Comment: If it was "labour-intensive or time-intensive" you could say "labour/time-intensive".

Comment: What is the name for this form of hyphenation (labour- ...) in the English grammar, so that I can read up on this?

Comment: @johann_ka suspended hyphens https://english.stackexchange.com/a/132002/196994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fowler recommends that you leave out the hyphen after *labour* there, because it is not strictly needed for comprehension. I don't have a reference on hand, but it is no doubt in his *Dictionary of Modern English Usage*, a highly respected style book.

Comment: Yep. The hyphen is allowed but not required. I like the look of it, though, and it disambiguates a few edge cases.

Comment: @JonPurdy: It is required in Dutch btw...

Comment: Interesting. I know sticklers who would say it’s required in English, but even for the normal case of compound adjectives (“a six-foot-tall man”) most people don’t use them and it’s not usually ambiguous (“a six foot tall man”). The only thing that bothers me is when people hypercorrect: e.g., “she was six years old” to “she was six-years-old”.

Comment: @JonPurdy: That is indeed annoying! The idea behind a *six-foot-tall man* is consistency: if we *always* hyphenate compound adjectives, we can depend upon this feature, and it becomes easier in general to immediately parse correctly a pot smoking hot and a pot-smoking hottie, even though strictly neither is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can hyphenate.

Though you have to realize that both "Time-intensive" and "Labor-intensive" are adjectives, qualifying the noun "Part"
I would personally take the conjunction "And" out. Try a noun after both the adjectives, for example  Time-intensive activities...  Labor-intensive jobs  etc.