# Should one suspend a hyphen when using "two- to three-digit" phrase used as an adjective?

Tags: hyphenation, numbers, suspended-hyphen

Example

> Sally alerted her accountant **to four to five digit** revenue discrepancies in the budget.

Should it be:

> ...to four to five digit revenue discrepancies

or with a suspended hyphen:

> ...to four- to five-digit revenue discrepancies

Comment: I've always used #1 except for large (>20) numbers, but I'd be interested to see what others have to say about this.

Comment: #3 and #4 make no sense whatsoever to me. Why would you hyphenate completely separate words in a sentence? Would you ever even consider writing, “It happened three-or-four-hours ago”? Surely not.

Comment: @maxton, thanks. I updated the question and example to make it more clear.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree, but my example wasn't very helpful. Could you take a look at the updated example? Thanks.

Comment: Aha! Now that’s an entirely different question, since now the numbers are part of a _compound adjective_, which is where hyphens become appropriate. Yes, I would use a suspended hyphen in those cases. Unfortunately, though, the question as it is asked now is a duplicate of at least a few others: [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39860/can-a-hyphen-be-used-without-anything-on-the-right-side) and [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113422/how-to-use-hyphens-appropriately-when-listing-multiple-hyphenated-terms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your new use case, the phrase is being used as an adjective, so you do need the hyphens.

> Sally alerted her accountant to **four- to five-digit** revenue discrepancies in the budget.

---

There seem to be a couple questions here, and I'll address them all, plus another error.

There is no reason at all to use hyphens here. It's *Four digits*, and *four digits ahead*, making it a range doesn't add hyphens.

I was taught to spell out integers less than 10, and ten or more when used together, so *four to five digits*, or *nine to ten digits*, *20 to 30 digits*.  Of course, for informal writing, just the numbers will be fine, and you can usually get away with using a hyphen instead of *to*: *4-5 digits*.

Finally, I don't think *digits* is the word you want here. A *digit* is just a character, a single glyph. If the other students average 50, *four digits ahead* would mean that Sally regularly finishes with a score of 500,000. You are looking for *points* or *percentage points*, depending on how the work is scored.

So the whole sentence you're looking for is

> Out of 100, Sally regularly finishes **four to five points** ahead of her classmates.

Comment: I was taught (I'll see if I can find an MLA or APA reference) to spell out numbers ten or less, and use digits for the larger numbers _except_ where they occur in the same phrase: thus "five cars", "20 cars", but "between five and fifteen cars".

Comment: Great points. What if the "digit" term actually described something else, like bonuses or revenue? Or if it were preceded by "to"? Consider the following: "Sally alerted her accountant to four to five digit revenue discrepancies in the budget." Would your answer remain the same?

Comment: @Ryan; No, the answer would be different (and you probably would include a suspended hyphen). But there are hundreds of possible questions in this area; we really can't answer all of them in comments. Could you please edit the question to ask what you really want to know?

Comment: @TimLymington, thanks for the advice. I updated the question to better reflect the my real life sentence structure. I didn't expect there to be different answers to the example proposed. Do you still advise a suspended hyphen?

Comment: @Kevin, would you also mind taking a look at the revised example? Would you still suggest not using a hyphen at all?

Comment: @Ryan Yes, you need a hyphen there (note, just the one). The usage is different because the phrase is a different part of speech.

Comment: Do you have a citation for not using the hyphen on the first (or apparently all-but-last) item? If you check out the various linked/duplicate questions, their answers cite style guides that stipulate the suspended hyphen.

Comment: @JohnY That's just what I was told in school, but I've always preferred having the hyphen anyway, so I've updated accordingly.