# Is the writer of this line trying to shorten "time-saving and labor-saving" into "time- and labor-saving"?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

Here's the paragraph is question below. The part I'm talking about is in **bold**.

> Festool has a reputation for producing expensive tools that provide
>   benefits the other brands either lack or end up chasing down. Superior
>   dust collection, clever ergonomics, precision adjustability, **unique
>   time- and labor-saving features**, a system-based approach to design,
>   and even careful consideration of the tools' Systainer carrying cases,
>   all speak of a design attention lavished on their products that you
>   simply don't see from most manufacturers these days.

Is the writer trying to shorten time-saving and labor-saving or just adding labor to time-saving? I understand what he's trying to say in general but I was a little confused with the construction of this sentence.

Comment: If you're interested in reading more about this, it's called a *suspended hyphen*: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39860/can-a-hyphen-be-used-without-anything-on-the-right-side/39862#39862

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"unique time- and labor-saving features" --->  "unique time-saving and labor-saving features"*

It is quite a common device.

Comment: A common time- and labour-saving device.

Comment: @user867 - Haha! :-D