# Listing multiple compound words

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

How do I list multiple things that are compound words?

In my own language I'm used to writing these lists like this:

*"I kicked foot-, basket-, and volleyball"*

The sentence is supposed to mean that I kicked all types of balls (football, basketball and volleyball). However, it does not seem correct to me. Should I write them as whole words, with or without hyphen, or how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a hyphen be used without anything on the right side?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39860/can-a-hyphen-be-used-without-anything-on-the-right-side) and addressed also at _A suspended hyphen in a list with only one hyphenated word_.

Comment: This is a case, however where the only words that appear with hyphens are not normally hyphenated words but whole closed up words (_football_, _basketball_, and _volleyball_). The hyphens in this case are there not to mark the reproduced portion of each hyphenated word but to mark where truncation of each whole word has occurred. I think that the situation is related but distinctly different from the one in the "-friendly" example cited in Edwin Ashworth's comment above.

Comment: I'm assuming from your profile name I think you are referring to Finnish as "own language". Even in case of Finnish that style (e.g. "jalka- ja koripallo" literally meaning foot- and basketball) is technically an abbreviation style that's common enough to be used in both written and spoken form. Finnish also has related abbreviation style for common prefix: e.g. "syntymäaika ja -paikka" meaning literally "birth date and -place" which is interepreted as "syntymäaika ja syntymäpaikka" meaning date of birth and birthplace. However, in Finnish, those abbreviations are always read as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basketball, football and volleyball fall under the category of closed compound words. These are combinations of two words that are not separated by a space or a hyphen. For more information on the types of compound words, check [this](http://www.k12reader.com/term/compound-words/) out.

So your sentence should essentially be

> *I kicked a football, a basketball and a volleyball.*

Suspended hyphenation(the case in a phrase like *pre- and post-war* implying *pre-war and post-war*) comes into picture only while dealing with hyphenated words. This [article](http://editingandwritingservices.com/suspended-hyphens/) will guide you through it.
Hope that helped!

Comment: Not according to CMOS, which allows 'both over- and underfed cats' as an abbreviated form of 'both overfed and underfed cats'. And I'd assume more people take advice from CMOS than from Judy Vorfeld.

Answer (score -1):

It only makes sense when the word has significance in isolation. Foot, volley, basket may not connect to your audience well. Either find a word that can group them. ( don't know if it exists in this case) For example - board games.

Comment: None of these 3 are "board games". Maybe you can suggest a different word, such as team sports?