# Is this a compound adjective, and if so, what parts of it should be capitalized in a title?

Tags: prepositions, capitalization, compound-adjectives

I am currently proofreading some documents which go by the title "Pre and Post Visit Materials". For the life of me, I can't decide whether "post visit" counts as a compound adjective in this instance and therefore needs a hyphen. If it is a compound adjective, then in the title would "Post-Visit" or "Post-visit" be correct? If it isn't a compound adjective, would anyone mind explaining to me why?

Also, is it acceptable to leave "pre" as a stand-alone word without any additional punctuation?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing multiple compound words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290115/listing-multiple-compound-words) You can check on whether _pre-visit_  and _post-visit_ are (a) compounds and (b) hyphenated, for instance at [vmfa.museum pre-visit and post-visit activities](https://www.vmfa.museum/learn-archive/pre-visit-and-post-visit-activities/), which also shows a way to capitalise your title.

Comment: Thus, << Pre- and Post-Visit Materials >> Although  << Pre- and Post-visit Materials >> is arguably more felicitous (but appearance will trump here).

Comment: Not so much a compound adjective as a complex noun with the prefixes "pre" and "post". "Pre- and Post-Visit" is a thus a complex noun modifying "Materials".