# Space-and time-efficient

Tags: hyphenation

This question has always haunted me, so I decided to settle it for good.
Suppose I am saying "We provide space-and time-efficient algorithm for approximating [the number of cats in apartment building]".
Here, is my us of hyphen in "space-and time-efficient" correct?

EDIT: So, one way of saying this is "Our algorithm is space efficient, and also time efficient". Now, I would like to shorten this by something like "space-and time-efficient". My question is, do I need a hyphen after "and"? Or, how to correctly hyphenate in this particular case? Although the links in the comments do deal with similar problems, their case is just that -- similar, but not identical to mine.

Comment: It’s never correct to use an em dash when a hyphen is required. Have you researched the difference between the two?

Comment: You haven't used em dashes (—); you've used hyphens (-). Are you asking how to hyphenate compound adjectives or are you asking about how to present parenthetical information? Any on-topic answer given will depend entirely on the topic of your question—which isn't clear.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: While the nominated duplicate may not at first glance seem relevant, please read the answer. Your phrase is almost correct, but *space-* needs a space after it (it shouldn't be hyphenated to *and*).

Comment: See also [Can a hyphen be used without anything on the right side](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39860/can-a-hyphen-be-used-without-anything-on-the-right-side)

Comment: The updated version of your sentence requires neither hyphens nor dashes. *Our algorithm is (both) space and time efficient.* If you aren't using hyphenation with the single words, then using a conjunction with them doesn't change that. However, if you said *I have a space-efficient heater* and *I have a time-efficient heater* (each being hyphenated), then the combination would be *I have a space- and time-efficient heater.*